# What is this glass bulb with two parallel electrodes on my PCB?

Tags: identification

Might be super obvious, but I've not encountered one of whatever this little dude is before:

[image: strangle little bulb-like thing]

I figured some sort of vacuum tube, but no idea beyond that. The two poles aren't linked. Found inside a heating control panel. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this side up for orientation or right angles?

Answer (score 35):

I think it is a neon lamp - possibly an NE-2.  The "I3" designator on the PC board tends to confirm that - "I" would indicate "indicator".

Comment: That must have been a tough call Peter.

Comment: It might be used as [overvoltage protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_lamp#Voltage_regulation).

Answer (score 13):

Neon lamp or gas filled surge arrester. Not likely a mercury tilt switch, since:
a) PCB mounted mercury switches are far more rare than neons/arresters
b) This looks like a PCB from a CRT monitor where gas filled arresters are very commonly used
c) There is no mercury bead visible

Answer (score 3):

On the right image you'll see there's some mercury at the bottom inside of the enclosure.

It is a [mercury tilt sensor/switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_switch).

[image]

Comment: That's just a weird reflection - I've given it a good eyeball and wiggled it about, definitely no mercury in there. Weird though, otherwise it looks identical to your pic.

Comment: I think that mercury you're seeing is a trick of the light. Looks more like a [neon bulb](http://www.surplussales.com/Images/Bulbs-Incan-Panel/Neon/lmp-NEON-23_1_lg.jpg) to me.

Comment: @slothgirl Hmm, have you *tilted* it though? Otherwise it might be something else... oh well.

Comment: @brhans It sure looks like it, though it's a weird placement for it.

Comment: They're sometimes used as sorta surge protectors in power supplies - so not intended to be seen.

Comment: Ceramic heaters need a tilt sensor so they dont burn the carpet and the house.  THey must have cut down the volume of mercury these days so its almost invisible (LOL). They certainly dont need a neon light.  But a gas tube surge suppressor seems like overkill protection for a ceramic heater? when I see an MOV. But if it is , the fuse is must have.

Comment: In a mercury sensor – as shown in your picture – the contacts/wires are at one end of the tube, allowing the mercury to sit at the other end (in normal orientation). In the OP's picture, the contacts/wires go almost to the end of the tube (and the leads where they enter don't appear insulated). If it _were_ a mercury switch, the mercury would be completing the circuit (virtually) all the time. Screams neon to me.

Comment: It's not a weird reflection and it's not mercury. It's part of the base of the fuseholder, behind the lamp, in that shot.

Comment: If it was a switch of any sort the circuit designation would start with "S" or even "SW", not "I"! It's an indicator. Hence, a lamp. Maybe used as a surge suppressor, as others have said.